# Pass http authentification and headers to modrestcurlclient request

Tags: curl, modx, modx-revolution

I try to make payment page on my site using payment system (bePaid). To make a payment I need to create token.
To create token I need to send POST request with authentification data, headers and JSON with parameters to payment system url.

In pure bash form it looks like

```
curl https://checkout.bepaid.by/ctp/api/checkouts -u shopId:shopKey -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '
{
  "checkout": {
    "order": {
      "amount": 1,
      "currency": "USD",
      "description": "Test"
    },
    "settings": {
      "decline_url": "http://www.example.com/decline",
      "fail_url": "http://www.example.com/fail",
      "notification_url": "http://www.example.com/notify",
      "success_url": "http://www.example.com/success"
    },
    "transaction_type": "payment",
    "version": 2
  }
}'
```

My site is on MODX Revolution. I know that it has its own CURL-client. From the documentation I see how to send a request

```
request( string $host, string $path, string $method = GET, array $params = array, array $options = array )
```

Accordingly to that `$host` is https://checkout.bepaid.by/ctp/api/checkouts, `$path` is '/', `method` is POST, `$params` is JSON. I don't know what is `$options` . If this is authentification data and headers - what is the syntax? If not, where I should pass that info?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the $options. If that array contains a key with value `modRestClient::OPT_USERPWD` (or `userpwd`) and you `shopId:shopKey` as value, that will be set as a BASIC AUTH header.